# Why is the expansion of universe continuously increasing?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, dark-energy

If our universe is expanding and the concept of the multiverse is true, then why is the rate of the expansion of the universe increasing? Surely it must decrease?

Comment: 1) Why is the multiverse theory necessarily true? 2) I don't see any relationship between the expansion of the universe and the multiverse.

Comment: How does it follow that the multiverse would make expansion decrease?

Comment: I have studied theory of parallel universe in which universe is considered as spherical and each universe is touched with next , so i think if our universe is expanding then may be other universe also , and after many centuries it's expansion will stop.......am i ryt or not i don't know....

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your theory that the universe is some kind of sphere touching other universes in some kind of multiverse isn't just a pet theory, its one that contradicts one of the most powerful principles we use.

Which is that the universe is isotropic and homogeneous in the largest scales and lack a special position. If there was a point of contact t then there would be a special position and what you see would depend on where you are compared to it and then we wouldn't know anything because every theory would give any possible prediction based on how close we are to a special point.

The isotropic homogeneous solutions that don't have a special point make actual predictions for us since they makes predictions that are he same everywhere. So we can test them. So we can do science.

But let's say an inability to be scientific wasn't a problem, so we wanted to consider your theory. Well, if the multiverse was expanding at an accelerating rate and the universes were forced to remain touching, then the expansion of the multiverse could be the cause of the universes expanding.

Of course we can't test it since we can't test a theory that is inhomogeneous and/or anisotropic.